Same Spark Job executing in Parallel for different days in different instance of AWS EMR have performance issues
While running the spark job (only one instance), it completes in 20-30 mins. However, the same code executes in multiple emr instance in parallel taking more time. Ex: I have 3 instance where each instance has 10 jobs each. Each job in an instance run in sequence however 3 jobs in different instance run in parallel.
Can there be S3 write taking time or Glue metadata updates?
Some details about the jobs
1.Process around 10 TB data in one instance.
2.Write in to same s3 bucket but different partitions.
3.It adds metadata into Glue.
4.There are intermediate bucketed tables.



Each job was writing data into same s3 folder but different partitions.There is hard limit from s3 write.[3,500 write requests or 5,500 read requests per second]. This was creating performance issues.
